# How do I fix an undefined error in my class?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a Javascript class for keyboard input. I'm trying to test my class but I'm getting undefined errors.

Contents of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Keyboard</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      canvas { border: 1px solid; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id ="title">Test Keyboard</h1>
    <script src="src/input.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contents of input.js

```
'use strict';

class Keyboard {

    constructor() {
        this.keysPressed = {}
        this.translateKeyCode = {
            49: 0x1,  // 1
            50: 0x2,  // 2
            51: 0x3,  // 3
            52: 0x4,  // 4
            81: 0x5,  // Q
            87: 0x6,  // W
            69: 0x7,  // E
            82: 0x8,  // R
            65: 0x9,  // A
            83: 0xA,  // S
            68: 0xB,  // D
            70: 0xC,  // F
            90: 0xD,  // Z
            88: 0xE,  // X
            67: 0xF,  // C
            86: 0x10  // V
        }

    }

    onNextKeyPressed(code) {
        //Override this in Fx0A - LD Vx, K
    }

    isPressed(event) {
        return this.keysPressed[this.translateKeyCode[event.keyCode]];

    }

    isDown(event) {
        console.log(`Pressed ${event.keyCode}`)
        this.keysPressed[this.translateKeyCode[event.keyCode]] = 1;
        this.onNextKeyPressed(event.keyCode);
        // We only want onNextKeyPressed to run once
        // After a Fx0A opcode
        this.onNextKeyPressed = function() {};
    }

    isUp(event) {
        console.log(`Released ${event.keyCode}`)
        delete this.keysPressed[this.translateKeyCode[event.keyCode]];
    }

}

let keyboard = new Keyboard();

window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboard.isDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyboard.isUp);
```

The expected result is for the code to run without errors.

The actual result is a Javascript undefined error at these lines upon keypress.

```
this.keysPressed[this.translateKeyCode[event.keyCode]] = 1;
this.onNextKeyPressed(event.keyCode);
delete this.keysPressed[this.translateKeyCode[event.keyCode]];
```

Comment: When you pass a function reference to an event handler it loses the binding to `this`. You can try: `window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboard.isDown.bind(keyboard));`

Answer (score 1):

Try preserving your bindings, something fairly simple with ES6:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => keyboard.isDown(ev));
window.addEventListener("keyup", (ev) => keyboard.isUp(ev));
```

The old-fashioned way for contrast:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) { keyboard.isDown(ev) });
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) { keyboard.isUp(ev) });
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I don't understand how that works though. Can you please explain the concept of a binding and how that change made it work? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is `this` needs to be set correctly in order for your code to work and one way to force that is to *call* the `isDown` function in the context of `keyboard`, as in `keyboard.isDown(ev)` If you just pass in `isDown` as a function it will call it with a different binding, `this` will refer to the event itself, which means you can't get access to your `Keyboard` instance. This kind of ambiguity happens a lot in JavaScript when passing a function that calls a function in a specific way versus passing in a function that gets called some arbitrary way.